# Can I configure Compass to output the CSS on a different drive?

Tags: css, windows, stylesheet, sass, compass-sass

Let's say that I have a Compass project on D:\Compass (this is where I keep my sources) and I want to output my generated stylesheets on E:\CSS, is that possible in any way? I tried changing the --css-dir but it won't work because it has to be relative to the project dir? Has anyone tried this before?

Answer (score 2):

I appreciate this is a bit of a rubbish answer, but perhaps it will help:

On most *nix systems you can do something like:

- Make the relevant folder on the drive you want to use.
- Create a symbolic link to the folder within your compass project
- Make that folder your compass output folder

Not sure of the exact process for windows, but I'm aware you can do symbolic links or something similiar: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link

Comment: +1 A symlink of D:\Compass\CSS to E:\CSS should work fine (If the program doesn't choke on it).